# Pass array and number of its values to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting

I need to pass and integer array and number of values in the array to the `sort(array[], count)` function. It should return the number of swaps, not comparisons, made by the bubble sort. This code compiles and runs but I do not get the right output. Sometimes it has me continuously entering values despite the `while(i < counter)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sort(int array[], int count);
int main(void){
    int numArray[100];
    int counter, value;

    printf("Enter array length \n");
    scanf("%d", &counter);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < counter){
        scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < counter){
        sort(numArray, counter);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < counter){
        printf("Values: %d\n", numArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int sort(int array[], int count){
    int i, j, temp;
    int swaps = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count-1; ++i){
        for(j=0; j<count-1-i; ++j){
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
                temp = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    return swaps;
}
```

Comment: `sort` doesn't return anything, nor does `sort(numArray, counter);` get anything.

Comment: I need to figure out how to return the number of swaps

Comment: `sort` needs to hold the number of swaps and then `return` it at the end.

Comment: So would I `return array;` ?

Comment: You don't need to because both `main` and `sort` have access to `numArray`/`array`.  You need another `int swaps = 0` variable and increment every time you are in the `if` statement: `if(array[j] > array[j+1])`.  At the end, `return swaps`.

Comment: Your for loops in `sort` look suspicious: You are mixing `i` and `j` in both. In fact the first loop checks that `j < count-1` but at this moment `j` is not yet assigned a value so if you are unlucky this condition is initially false. I think you rather want: `for (i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < count - 1 - i; ++j) `

Comment: You don't print the return value when you call `sort`

Comment: I change those things around and is that what you meant @FiddlingBits

Comment: You should not incrementally edit the code in your question until you reach the desired goal because future readers won't recognise the original problem. It will seem like a question without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is now, you only need to call `sort(numArray, counter)` once and "catch" the returned value:

```
int totalSwaps = sort(numArray, counter);
```

And print the result once:

```
printf("the number of swaps in bubblesort is: %d", totalSwaps);
```

Comment: How will that change anything?

Comment: would i call `int totalSwaps = sort(numArray, counter);` within my while loop? Or are you saying not to? its part of my assignment

Comment: You should not, call it only once and remove the (2nd) while in your main

Comment: I have to have a second while loop. Its part of my assignment

Comment: This is the assignment `Now return to the
main()
function and insert a third loop
after
the reading loop and
before
the
printing loop. This should iterate exactly
counter
times; the body of this loop should invoke the
s
ort
()
function, passing it
numA
rray
and
counter
.
This is the loop that controls
the number of
passes through the array
.`

Comment: I don't see the assignment, it just says what to do.

Comment: Well I answered your question. If you have another question about a specific programming problem you can ask another question. Stackoverflow doesn't make your homework, ofc.

Comment: @CodyHutto I don't understand the point in adding another loop that does the same over and over again by calling your function with the same arguments and not changing any global state :).

Comment: I got it to work but It wont tell me the number of swaps heres the output    `Swaps: 0
Values: 0
Values: 1
Values: 2
Values: 2
Values: 3
Values: 4
Values: 5
Values: 5
Values: 5
Values: 6
Values: 8
Values: 12
Values: 14
Values: 23
Values: 34
Values: 45
Values: 45
Values: 67
Values: 89
Values: 100
`

Comment: @CodyHutto What is your console input?

Comment: @halex neither do I. Thats what the teacher wants is there anyway I could email you?